# indexOf returning -1

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexof

I am searching for a string in a set and keep having -1 returned

Here is my code below:

```
Set<String> myTokens = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("myTokens", new HashSet<String>());

    if(String.valueOf(myTokens).contains(auth.getUid())){
        int i = Arrays.asList(myTokens).indexOf(auth.getUid());
        Log.w(TAG, "Index position of token is: " + String.valueOf(i) + " where the token array is: " + myTokens + "auth.getUid() is: " + auth.getUid());
```

My output:

```
Index position of token is: -1 where the token array is: [0o75WmAAlTcWUzxgbcleBQSVQSr1, Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2, VatU5fy1U4cgTc3uBBiGX7G7kuT2] auth.getUid() is: Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2
```

Not sure why I keep getting -1, any ideas?

People have suggested that the value for auth.getUid() is not in the set.. But **"Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2"** appears in the set which I have put at the bottom of the question

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `indexOf()` returns -1 when the element is not found in the Set

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, the value "Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2" is in the set?

Comment: auth.getUid() "Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2" value is not stored in the Set That is why you get the -1. When Set is no value found in the set

Comment: Try to print myTokens and see

Comment: Hi, I have printed the output at bottom of my question using Log My output is: Index position of token is: -1 where the token array is: [0o75WmAAlTcWUzxgbcleBQSVQSr1, Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2, VatU5fy1U4cgTc3uBBiGX7G7kuT2] auth.getUid() is: Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2

Comment: Why do you convert the `Set` to `String`, first? `Set` has already a `.contains` method that works pretty well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(myTokens)
```

Since `myTokens` is a `Set<String>`, this expression has type `List<Set<String>>`, not `List<String>`.

Since a `List<Set<String>>` can't contain `String` elements, `indexOf(someString)` will always return -1.

You should use

```
new ArrayList<>(myTokens)
```

instead which makes a copy of the set, with elements in their iteration order at the time when this expression is evaluated.

However: `myTokens` is (or, at least, it *can* be) a `HashSet`, which is an unordered collection. As such, "index" has no meaning, since there is no guarantee the index would be the same if you calculated it again. Picking zero if the set contains the element is an equally-valid strategy.

Comment: Heh, hadn't noticed that when i wrote my answer, i assumed `Arrays.asList` had an overload for sets. +1

Comment: Thanks mate! No idea how to implement this using shared preferences lol

Comment: Is there anyway U can get index of a set, as I dont know how to change my current implementation using set to arrays?

Comment: Sets are unordered collections. "index" has no real meaning.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I am in process of implementing arrays atm.. Quite complicated as now I need to searilise the object but yeah should be ok...

Comment: @AndyTurner I have tried to convert the HashSet to an ArrayList which works correctly, but i is still giving -1 in this situation 
        List<String> myTokensList = new ArrayList <String> (myTokens);

        int i = Arrays.asList(myTokensList).indexOf(theToken);

Comment: That's not what I said (or at least, not what I meant): `new ArrayList<>(myTokens).indexOf(...)`. `Arrays.asList(myTokensList)` is a `List<List<String>>`, for the exact same reason that `Arrays.asList(myTokens)` is a `List<Set<String>`.